# How can Intellij not put labels on a separate line?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, code-formatting

For compatibility with an existing codebase (based on Eclipse's default formatter), to use Intellij's formatter, I want it to not put a newline after labels.

I want Intellij's formatter to create this, following existing style

```
outer: for (int i ...
```

but it creates this:

```
outer:
        for (int i ...
```

I have explored Code Style->Java->Wrapping and Braces but find nothing relevant.

How do I set this?

Comment: Note : There is a plugin called "Eclipse Formatter" for IntelliJ.

Comment: It's not possible. Labels are crap anyway. You'd be better off saying that any code changes to code using a label must be refactored to remove the label, rather than hoping a keyboard shortcut is going to solve all your problems.

Comment: @Michael I agree about the labels, but refactoring them just to achieve format-compatibility would prevent our use of   Intellij.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle I in fact used that, but this is a corner case that is not working correctly

Comment: @JoshuaFox my point about the keyboard shortcut was mainly that if you are relying on auto formatting from an IDE before committing then your process is fundamentally broken. Enforce code style as part of your build, or have a pre receive hook automatically format the code. Using this a reason to not use intellij is really bad...

Comment: @michael I don't want a keyboard shortcut. I do want a hook to automatically format the code. The format must be identical to what we now have to avoid repeatedly disrupting thousands of files

Comment: Why would you want a hook that's intrinsically linked to an IDE? Devs should be able to use whatever environment they want. You should use a tool like Spotless if you want to automate a task like this.

Comment: Feel  free to create feature request on YouTrack: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.